# Hoiw to get the selection fields of a query

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to dynamically specify any AOT query, then read back the columns and values.

I am pretty close.  The only problem is that it lists ALL fields in each datasource instead of just the fields specified to return values in the query.

Any suggestions how I can get this to return query result fields only, instead of all columns in the datasource?

Thanks,

- Brad

  ```
          while (queryRun.next())
          {
              //parse through each datasource
              for(i = 1; i <= workingQuery.dataSourceCount(); i++)
              {
                  //get all fields in this data source
                  qbfl = workingQuery.dataSourceNo(i).fields();
                  cnt = qbfl.fieldCount();  //this comes up with the correct number, so AX is aware of the right number

                  //DID NOT WORK EITHER common = workingQuery.dataSourceNo(i).getNo();
                  common = queryRun.get(workingQuery.dataSourceNo(i).table());
                  dicttable = new DictTable(common.TableId);
                  fieldcnt   = dicttable.fieldCnt();
                  //parse through the fields and set the values in the new table
                  for (i = 1; i <= fieldcnt; i++)
                  {
                      //write the field names and values
                      fieldid   = dicttable.fieldCnt2Id(i);
                      dictfield = new dictfield(common.TableId,fieldid);
                      info(dicttable.fieldName(fieldid));
                      info(common.(dictfield.id()));                            
                  }
              }
          }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the system class [QueryBuildFieldList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/querybuildfieldlist.aspx) using `fieldCount` and `field`methods. Also check [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Query_class#QueryBuildFieldList).

```
Query q = new Query(queryStr(CustTable));
QueryBuildDataSource qbds = q.dataSourceTable(tableNum(CustTable));
QueryBuildFieldList qbfl = qbds.fields();
Counter i;
for (i = 1; i <= qbfl.fieldCount(); i++)
    info(new DictField(qbds.table(), qbfl.field(i)).name());
```